# Add a flag to bash script

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have the following bash script:

```
if
    ps aux | grep -E "[i]tunes_exporter.py" > /dev/null
then
    echo "Script is already running. Skipping"
else
    "$DIR/itunes_exporter.py"
fi
```

I want to add an `-f` flag to the `itunes_exporter.py` command. For example:

```
"$DIR/itunes_exporter.py -f"
```

But then I get the following error:

> -f: No such file or directory

How would I properly add the `-f` flag?

Comment: You can use `grep -q` instead of piping to `/dev/null`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should write it `"$DIR/itunes_exporter.py" -f`